# Arithmetic help on a creationists view of radiocarbon decay

Tags: linear-algebra, arithmetic

Just wanted to see if anyone could provide an arithmetic or algebraic explanation as to how this author (Brown 1990) derived $e^{+a(F-4000)} = 20$, or $a = \frac{2.996}{(F-4000)}$ .  All I can see is the solution to $e^{-a(F-4000)} = 0.05$, or $a = \frac{-2.996}{(F-4000)}$; please see my workflow under the POSSIBLE SOLUTION heading, section listed towards the end of this document, in **bold text**.  Is it just some strange coincidence that $\frac{1.0}{0.05} = 20$, and that the natural log of 20 is approximately 2.996 as well?  It seems Brown achieved this figure just to avoid the negative value of $a$ since it would violate his Equation 3.   Please see the attached article (Brown 1990; https://grisda.org/assets/public/publications/origins/17056.pdf) for details to Brown's methodology and solutions.  Just for reference, at the end of this document I list an example of the actual radiocarbon dating formula, under the heading HALF LIFE DECAY FORMULA FOR C-14.

Again, I just want to see if any of your group, with far more mathematical insight than this biologist has, can prove Brown’s calculations.  My suspicion is that Brown formulated his equations to suite his resolve that the carbon 14 isotope can be no older that the date of the great flood, that his convictions insist occurred around 5730 BP (years before 1950).  Brown’s equations and explanations, taken verbatim from his 1990, article are listed below in *italics* (i.e. from the explanations of Equation 1 through Equation 3).

*For the major readjustment period following the Flood we can presume that radiocarbon levels in the atmosphere may be represented by Equation 1:*

*Equation 1*
*$$A = A_1(1 - e^{-at})$$*
*by setting t = (F-T), with F equal to a biblically based BP date for the Flood, and T representing real time BP,as i n Equation 2:*

*Equation 2*
*$$A = A_1[1 - e^{-a(F-T)}]$$*
*To evaluate the parameter a in Equation 2 we can presume A was equal to or better than 0.9 A1 at T equal to 4000, since C-14 ages based on interaction with the atmosphere have a better than 95% agreement with real-time historical age over the range of T from zero to 3500. To obtain a trial value for a we can set

$$0.95A_1 = A_1[1 - e^{-a(F-T)}]$$ at $T = 4000$, which gives $$e^{-a(F-4000)} = 0.05$$, Or $$e^{+a(F-4000)} = 20$$; from which $$a = \frac{2.996}{(F-4000)}$$.
With this value for $a$, the activity at $T$ years BP as given by Equation 2
becomes (Equation 3):*

*Equation 3*
*$$A = A_1[1 - e^{\frac{-2.996(F-T)}{(F-4000)}}]$$*

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

**This is my solution to how Brown derived $e^{-a(F-4000)} = 0.05$ but not $e^{+a(F-4000)} = 20$**

**Beginning with $$0.95A_1 = A_1(1 - e^{-a(F-T)})$$ Distribute $A_1$ to the parentheses; this yields $$0.95A_1 = A_1 - A_1e^{-a(F - T)}$$ Subtract $A_1$ from both sides; resulting in $$-0.05A_1 =  -A_1e^{-a(F - T)}$$ Divide both sides by $-A_1$ (this cancels out the term $A_1$); resulting in $$0.05 = e^{-a(F - T)}$$ Substitute $4000$ for the $T$ value; this yields $$0.05 = e^{-a(F - 4000)}$$ Take the natural log of both sides; resulting in $$2.996 = -a(F-4000)$$ Divide both sides by $(F-4000)$; giving us $$\frac{2.996}{(F-4000)} = -a$$ Which can also be expressed as $$a = \frac{-2.996}{(F-4000)}$$**

**This would solution would result in Equation 3 being $$A = A_1[1 - e^{-(\frac{-2.996}{F-4000})(F-T)}]$$ which can also be expressed as $$A = A_1[1 - e^{\frac{2.996(F-T)}{(F-4000)}}]$$**

**I can only postulate that since Euler's number is now being raised to a positive value, thus Brown's Equation 3 is now an equation for exponential growth and he chose to use the reciprocal of $e^{-a(F-4000)} = 0.05$ (i.e. $e^{+a(F-4000)} = 20$) to achieve an equation for exponential decay.**

**I just can't fathom how this was calculated from**

**$$0.95A_1 = A_1[1 - e^{-a(F-T)}]$$**

**at $T = 4000$.**

**It just doesn't seem valid to change to the reciprocal value on a whim.  I'm sure that I'm going about it the wrong way.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also please check out the link to Brown's article if you have the time.  Thank you all in advance for any assistance.**

HALF LIFE DECAY FORMULA FOR C-14

$$N(t) = N_0e^{rt}$$

Where $N_0$ is the original quantity of the element, $e$ is Euler’s constant (2.71828…), $r$ is the half life of the element.  This is determined by the natural logarithm multiplied by one half, divided by the time it takes to decay by one half.  For carbon-14 this figure is $\frac{ln(0.5)}{5730}$, $t$ is the time that has expired; therefore $N(t)$ is the amount that still remains after a period of time $t$.

To illustrate this formula, we can say that after 40,000 years, 1 mole of carbon will have decayed by:

$$N(t) = N_0e^{rt}$$

$N(40,000 yrs) = (1 mol)(2.71828183)^{(\frac{ln(0.5)}{5730 yrs})(40,000 yrs)}$

$N(40,000 yrs) = (1 mol)(2.71828183)^{(\frac{-0.69314718}{5730 yrs})(40,000 yrs)}$

$N(40,000 yrs) = (1 mol)(2.71828183)^{(\frac{-0.00012097}{yrs})(40,000 yrs)}$

$N(40,000 yrs) = (1 mol)(2.71828183)^{-4.83872377}$

$N(40,000 yrs) = 0.00791715mol$

In grams of carbon 14, this would be:

$N(40,000yrs) = (0.00791715mol)(\frac{18.035 g}{mol}) = 0.14278580025 g$

In other words, assuming it would be easy to isolate 1 mole (or 18.035g/mol) of carbon-14, in the first place.  After 40,000 years have passed, beta decay would have left only 0.791715% of the original carbon-14 remaining.  In in other words, only 0.143 g of the original 18.035 g would be left.  Since carbon-14 makes up just one trillionth, or 0.0000000001%, of the total carbon on Earth (the majority being the stable isotope carbon-12), one can see how difficult it would be to measure the infinitesimally small amount of carbon-14 that would remain in a biological specimen after 40,000 years have passed.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: Just learning it as we speak.  I'll repost with proper formatting.  Thanks, that's why I attached an image with the formulas written out in word.

Comment: The log of $.05$ is $-2.996$ so I have no idea what you are puzzled by.